# Use more available space for search box in top bar

Tags: feature-request, design, search, top-bar

Today I noticed that top bar's search box width was increased. It's a good news! But I can't understand why it's not increased even more. In particular, the right offset could be minimized as done for the left part of search box:

> [image: right]
>
> [image: left]

Comment: In one word: diamond. (That's where the mod diamond menu is located, as far as I know)

Comment: @ShadowWizard why the rest of the world should suffer because of the handful of diamond owners?

Comment: Because having two sets of design (one for mods and one for non mods) means double development time, double money spent, etc. I prefer that money to go on developing single design, with a small unused space, that would be good and without bugs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard pf-f-f ... what about one, but adaptive design? Do they know about it?

Comment: Get hired as developer for SE and you'll know. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Get hired as developer to punish downvoters! :) BTW acording your comment. Should I tag this question with [support] to get an answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard 1. As a frontend developer I'd like to say that you are wrong about need in two versions of desing for that. 2. As a moderator on ruSO I'd like to say that you are wrong about this place and it's not used for diamond: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyclO.png

Comment: @Qwertiy as for #2 try with small screen (full site, responsive design) and pretty sure diamond will take all the space.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, nope, updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

This style is made by

```
.top-bar .-secondary {
    ...
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 48px;
    ...
```

And it is not used for any purpose including moderator notifications as far as I can tell:

[image: screenshot]

And on the smaller screen:

[image: non mod]
[image: mod]

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented (fixed) now:

> [image: top bar is fixed]

Both right and left margins around search box in the top bar have same width now.

But it seems that is only for users that have all kind of badges (bronze, silver, gold). Because in case of only bronze badges search box right margin is still larger than left one:

> [image: only bronze badges]